MS-Excel Sort with special chars: wrong result
I have some multi-language data, that means I use special chars like:
á, À, ä, Ü, ß, etc.
Sorting cells containg this chars, shows this result (as an example):

that means: a < á < à < ä ... etc.
Fine! It is something like: a < b < c < d
The probelm rises as  I add some other cells:

Because "a < á", when I sort all the values, I expect this sequence:

but surprise, the sort shows:

My first question is simply "why???"
But the real problem is that when I process these strings in VBA (macro), VBA evaluates (correctly!) "aX" < "ä",
but in the sorted list:
"ä" < "aX".
Any idea why the sort is not working correctly?
I already checked all the possible options in Excel Sort ...

It looks like a feature or a bug. You need to claim Microsoft. Keep us informed please. I have no explanation for such behavior. The text sort expected except for that can be treated as a number.

ASCII chars are sorted as expected: ! !1 !4 " "2 "5 # #3 #6

Unclear what is going on and to make things more confusing =CODE() of your various lonely a's on my default code page gives a (97 0x61) < á (225 0xE1)< à (224 0xE0)< ä (228 0xE4). Note that the middle pair are swapped in values cf their XL sort ordering.

@Martin
and that is correct!
that is bacause if I sort the following strings:
"a", "á", "aXYZ", "áXYZ"
I expect:
"a", "aXYZ", "á", "áXYZ"
but the result is:
"a", "á", "aXYZ", "áXYZ"
How do you explain it?

Typical of &%^($)( Microsoft coders! Check MSKB just in case and then file a bug report. I think I have it. The sort rule is converting accented characters to their unaccented form and then using length as a presort. It puts words with/without accents close to each other but in a funny way! The location of abc after sorting surprised me!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajfb5LSbQVM&t=2508s&pp=ygUddGhyZSBpcyBubyBzdWNoIHRoaW5nIGFzIHRleHQ%3D

@Michal i think https://youtu.be/ajfb5LSbQVM?t=1462 is a better timestamp for sort related. just my 2sen.

@Michal thx the video is really inspiring: it explains lots of "strange" situations ... but the real explanation for my case I suppose is from the second comment of Martin Brown

@Martin: I think you got the problem! Thx a lot!

Thx to @(Martin Brown) because he found the problem.
I copy here his comment:

"... The sort rule is converting accented characters to their
unaccented form and then using length as a presort. It puts words with/without accents close to each other but in a funny way! The location of abc after sorting surprised me! –  Martin Brown"

